# perform two different functions and one submit button using flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am trying to perform two different functions with single submit button, the below script shows the example of what I am trying to get. Thank you for helping me.
Expected solution -->  when I click on submit button file has to upload along with map2 has redirect to mapRedirect url.

```
from flask import flask, render_template, flash, request, redirect,url_for
@app.route('/map2')
def map_2():
    return render_template('map2.html')
    

@app.route('/mapRedirect', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def onMap():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['nm']
        return redirect(f"map2")

@app.route('/proc')
def upload_file():
    ## file upload script
    return render_template('proc.html')
```

map2.html

```
<iframe name = "Ifrmp", id='mp', src="map2" >
```

proc.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="Ifrmp">
<input type="submit" id='btn' name="nm" value="submit>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to perform AJAX requests on those two functions.

```
<input type="submit" id='btn' form value="Click" onclick = 'button1();button2()'>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    
    function button1() {
        $.get("/button1");
    }

    function button2() {
        $.post("/button2");
    }

</script>
```